# Celery: auto discovery does not find tasks module in app

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I have the following setup with a fresh installed celery and django 1.4:

settings.py:

```
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()

BROKER_HOST = 'localhost'
BROKER_PORT = 5672
BROKER_USER = 'user'
BROKER_PASSWORD = 'password'
BROKER_VHOST = 'test'

[...]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'djcelery',
    'south',
    'compressor',
    'testapp',
]
```

testapp/tasks.py:

```
from celery.task import task

@task()
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Message delivery to the celeryd works fine, but the task is always unregistered (so auto discovery does not seem to work correctly here). Only if I import the tasks module in `tasks/__init__.py` the task is found and I can use it.

Also the documentation was a little confusing about the decorator import, but I think this is the right one now.

Where is the bug in my setup?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This was a bug in django-celery 2.5.4, please upgrade to 2.5.5!

Comment: I'm gonna test this later, but as I see on Pypi, 2.5.5 was released yesterday, so this is a really good information!

Answer (score 39):

Add [`CELERY_IMPORTS`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/configuration.html#celery-imports) to your settings.py:

```
CELERY_IMPORTS = ('testapp.tasks',)
```

Import all the tasks in `testapp.tasks.__init__` file

Then **Celery** will import all tasks from testapp.tasks folder and name them as they are

Comment: I tested this, but it did not help. Only the import in the `__init__.py` of the app got the task working.

Comment: Had the same problem with 2.5.5. Adding CELERY_IMPORTS worked for me, but only together with an explicit name argument in the decorator. Simply using @task() raises a KeyError.

Answer (score 11):

For any one who stumbles here looking for similar problem solution.

In my case it was switching from old module bases `INSTALLED_APPS` setting to a new [AppConfig](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/applications/#configuring-applications) based configuration.

> New applications should avoid default_app_config. Instead they should require the **dotted path to the appropriate AppConfig subclass to be configured explicitly in INSTALLED_APPS**.

To fix this you should change the way you feed packages to celery, as stated here in the [2248 Celery issue](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2248#issuecomment-97404667):

```
from django.apps import apps
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: [n.name for n in apps.get_app_configs()]
```

Instead of [the old Celery 3 way](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-celery-with-django):

```
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

Comment: And note that if you're using Celery 4, the bug was fixed -- https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3341-- and you can do `app.autodiscover_tasks()`

Comment: yes,for example, if I put 'blog.apps.BlogConfig' in my INSTALLED_APPS，celery can't find that.I have to put 'blog' in INSTALLED_APPS that celery can find

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue with django 1.4.1 celery 3.0.9 and fixed it by naming the task.

@task() -> @task(name='testapp.tasks.add')

Comment: Did you make any other changes? I am having the same issue, but just adding a name doesn't seem to solve it

Comment: I needed to restart the celery client. But I didn't make any other changes.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I couldn't figure out the problem until I tried to import the tasks in shell (`python` or `python manage.py shell`).

```
>>> from project_name.tasks import task_add
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you have to import the "Celery app instance" and declare a task like this:

```
from project_name.celery import app

@app.task
def video_process_task(video_id):
    pass
```

note that there's a celery.py file in the project_dir/project_name folder, which declares the celery instance, like this:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project_name.settings')
app = Celery('project_name')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

as instructed in the [official documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html).

also, you must register the task, in one of these three ways:

- the CELERY_IMPORTS variable in Django project's settings.py file as in dgel's answer
- passing `bind=True` to the decorator like: `@app.task(bind=True)`
- if you set autodiscovery for celery like it is done above in the line `app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)`
  , each Django application's folder can contain a tasks.py file, and the tasks declared inside it will be automatically registered

note that changes to the tasks REQUIRE A CELERY RESTART to take effect

Comment: a celery restart is not work for me, I need to delete the __pycache__ folder manule. to make it auto discovery the task in the tasks.py files.. what's the problem here??

Comment: I think you need to manually import your tasks to **settings.py**. I am on windows and my celery version is 3.1.25 . I solve the issue with manual import

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to **Umair A.'s** answer, there was an `ImportError` exception in my tasks.py file that was causing Celery to not register the tasks in the module. All other module tasks were registered correctly.

This error wasn't evident until I tried importing the Celery task within a Python Shell. I fixed the bad import statement and then the tasks were successfully registered.