# Daemonizing Celery--No module named 'celery' error

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celeryd, daemons

I'm trying to daemonize Celery 4.3.0 on Ubuntu 18 following the [official documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html#daemon-systemd-generic). This is for a Django project to off-load intensive tasks.

When the server is running the celery.service should make the Celery worker available to process tasks. However, Apache2 won't even run. If I `tail` the Apache log I see:

```
[Sun Sep 29 07:42:07.621273 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 2648:tid 140134825535232] [remote 92.4.204.209:55952]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
[Sun Sep 29 07:42:07.621279 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 2648:tid 140134825535232] [remote 92.4.204.209:55952]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Sun Sep 29 07:42:07.621285 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 2648:tid 140134825535232] [remote 92.4.204.209:55952]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
[Sun Sep 29 07:42:07.621291 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 2648:tid 140134825535232] [remote 92.4.204.209:55952]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
[Sun Sep 29 07:42:07.621297 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 2648:tid 140134825535232] [remote 92.4.204.209:55952]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Sun Sep 29 07:42:07.621303 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 2648:tid 140134825535232] [remote 92.4.204.209:55952]   File "/var/www/html/examgap/examgap/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
[Sun Sep 29 07:42:07.621307 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 2648:tid 140134825535232] [remote 92.4.204.209:55952]     from .celery import app as celery_app
[Sun Sep 29 07:42:07.621313 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 2648:tid 140134825535232] [remote 92.4.204.209:55952]   File "/var/www/html/examgap/examgap/celery.py", line 5, in <module>
[Sun Sep 29 07:42:07.621317 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 2648:tid 140134825535232] [remote 92.4.204.209:55952]     from celery import Celery
[Sun Sep 29 07:42:07.621333 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 2648:tid 140134825535232] [remote 92.4.204.209:55952] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'celery'
```

Celery is definitely installed for Python3. I can run the Celery worker for my app standalone using `celery -A examgap worker -l warning`--just not as a daemon.

I can also import celery if I launch a Python3 shell.

I've looked at several existing SO questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43969290) and think I've eliminated some possibilities. For example, the daemon user is ubuntu and this has rwx permissions for my project folder.

Still I think the problem lies with my celery.service file and the command that starts the daemon either not accessing the right folder or using the right permissions.

Here's my `/etc/systemd/system/celery.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Celery Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=ubuntu
Group=ubuntu
EnvironmentFile=/etc/conf.d/celery
WorkingDirectory=/opt/celery
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi start ${CELERYD_NODES} -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}'
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi stopwait ${CELERYD_NODES} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE}' ExecReload=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi restart ${CELERYD_NODES} -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Here's my `/etc/conf.d/celery` too:

```
# Name of nodes to start
# here we have a single node
CELERYD_NODES="eg1"
# or we could have three nodes:
#CELERYD_NODES="w1 w2 w3"

# Absolute or relative path to the 'celery' command:
#CELERY_BIN="/usr/local/bin/celery"
#CELERY_BIN="/virtualenvs/def/bin/celery"
#Think I installed Celery only for user ubuntu
CELERY_BIN="/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/celery"

#CELERYD_CHDIR="/var/www/html/examgap/"
# App instance to use
# comment out this line if you don't use an app
CELERY_APP="examgap"
# or fully qualified:
# CELERY_APP="examgap.tasks:app"

# How to call manage.py
CELERYD_MULTI="multi"

# Extra command-line arguments to the worker
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"

# - %n will be replaced with the first part of the nodename.
# - %I will be replaced with the current child process index
#   and is important when using the prefork pool to avoid race conditions.
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n%I.log"
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="INFO"
```

Edit 2: Changed the WorkingDirectory to my project directory and now the celery service is running. Yet the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'celery'` persists.

Answer (score 0):

```
[Sun Sep 29 07:42:07.621313 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 2648:tid 140134825535232] [remote 92.4.204.209:55952]   File "/var/www/html/examgap/examgap/celery.py", line 5, in <module>
```

Seems like you have your own *celery.py*, if so you should rename it to avoid import problems

Answer (score 0):

Here I let some links that look excellent. Just now I'm doing the same.

1. https://realpython.com/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/
   (recommended)
2. http://blog.fixter.org/hospedando-django-celery-rabbitmq-en-aws-parte-1/
   (i think it's tricky way)
3. https://dev.to/idrisrampurawala/deploying-django-with-celery-and-redis-on-ubuntu-3fo6 (level pro)

I hope this work for you.